# Customize search results page

Tags: views, search, 10

Is there a specific way to customize the search results page in Drupal 10? I would like to change the look of how the results are displayed. I have used Views to create the look how list items but I do not see an option for the search results? For example, how would I turn the search results into a list of bootstrap cards? I would like the list the results as cards with field values showing. I can do something similar with my content and Views but I can't figure out how to do this with the search results page.

I am hoping for a solution that does not require editing template files.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I think you shall have to define what you mean by "customize" in order to get an answer, given that you have added the requirement that there are no edits to template files.

Comment: @cilefen I have edited the question. I hope this is more clear. Basically I want to be able to make Bootstrap cards out of the search results.

Comment: You can do this in a custom preprocess function if you don't want to use a twig template.